# Seeking scholarly siddur with sources

Tags: tefilla, history, product-recommendation, prayer-book

Is there a well-sourced, scholarly siddur/work on the siddur/website that discusses the origins of the various prayers? Where can I find it?

Comment: I just acquired one which has some of the info you seek in its Hebrew notes (name when I get the chance), but you might also try http://www.beureihatefila.com/

Comment: @Danno's sit reference is an excellent one. I use it quite frequently. Be aware, though, that frequently some of the articles have "hidden" supplements that may be unrelated to the topic displayed on the link. While I don't know of a siddur, you might try Macy Nulman's book, Encyclopedia of Jewish Prayer. (Partially visible on http://books.google.com/books/about/The_encyclopedia_of_Jewish_prayer.html?id=lhcZAQAAIAAJ.) I studied with Cantor Nulman many years ago. His knowledge is excellent. If you don't find anything, contact the YU Belz School of Jewish Music. Ping me if you need the #.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eizur Eliyahu is very scholarly, it is technically a siddur according to the nusach of the Gr"a but attempts to get the text closest to what the Gr"a had. (possibly available [Here](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=eizur%20eliyahu&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftheseforimsale.com%2Fproducts%2Fh60-02-044y&ei=v98BVfeKOcrZarW9grgP&usg=AFQjCNHLmbviKZWYIBBTlPkxLy3KpdpcjQ&sig2=hk_4swNeU-n7y8H0vgu86g&bvm=bv.87920726,d.d2s))

Also Rav Ahron Lopiansky put a siddur together called [Aliyos Eliyahu](https://www.eshelpublications.com/store/p5/Siddur_Aliyos_Eliyahu_w%2F_Masores_Hatefilla.html), featuring notes on the bottom that trace the sources of each tefillah and its Talmudic Source

Answer (score 3):

While not a siddur in form or intent I believe it is hard to beat Elbogen's book [Jewish Liturgy: A comprehensive history](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Jewish_Liturgy.html?id=Bp99QgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)

It goes through pretty much everything in siddurim and machzorim with an attempt to track its source and evolution. It might not be the medium you're looking for, but it certainly provides the content.

Answer (score 2):

ואני תפילתי by Rabbi David Meir Riachi.
It is laid out in Gemara style and brings sources as well as delving into those for all tefillas. Rabbi Riachi is the author of the Simanim Tikkun Korim; and as always has put immense effort in his creation.

Answer (score 1):

This scholarly Siddur with tziyunim mekoros vehaaros might be exactly what you’re looking for. It’s on Nusach Ari but it compares different Nuschaos and their sources, so it’s basically an all in one.

[סדור רבינו הזקן עם ציונים מקורות והערות](https://hebrewbooks.org/30450)

> סדור רבינו הזקן הוא מהדורה מדעית של סידור האדמו"ר הזקן.
> בשנת תשס"ג - שנת המאתיים להדפסת סידורו של האדמו"ר הזקן בפעם הראשונה, הוציא לאור הרה"ג ר' לוי יצחק רסקין, דיין ומו"צ דקהילת חב"ד בלונדון, אנגליה. את הסידור עם ציונים מקורות והערות.
> בסידור זה הוא מדייק על כל תיבה מנין מקורה והוגה בדקדוקה וזיקוקה. כן מברר על כל דבר מהי ההלכה הנוגעת למקום זה, וכיצד נוהגים בפועל. -ChabadPedia

Here’s an example:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

Another good option is [סידור אוצר התפלות](https://hebrewbooks.org/57995). It is a two-volume set with multiple classic commentaries and also the full text of some classic halachic works, esp. Derech Hachaim of Rabbi Yaakov Loberbaum of Lisa.